# How to get a particular upcoming week day for the entered datestring using Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am a beginner in Java and new to this web world as well. I have a requirement to implement in my assignment project as below:

We need to add the days in input date such that it create the date of upcoming Monday.

example 1: If DateString = 17/02/2015 (Tuesday) then Output Date = 23/02/2015 (Monday).

example 2: If DateString = 18/02/2015 (Wednesday) then output Date = 23/02/2015 (Monday).

example 3: If DateString = 23/02/2015 (Monday) then output Date = 02/03/2015 (Monday).

input:Date string 
output: upcoming Monday for the entered Date string

Comment: That doesn't sound like you're really trying to get the day name - you're trying to advance a date to the next occurrence of a particular date. Now, which version of Java are you using? If you're using Java 8, I'd definitely recommend using this with `java.time`. If you're not, can you use Joda Time? Both are *much* better than `java.util.Date`/`Calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct, I guess below code is what you are looking for -

```
String dateString = "23/02/2015";

Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE,7);

System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ParseException{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter date(dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
            String input = br.readLine();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = df.parse(input);
            cal.setTime(date);
            int toAdd = (9 -cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE,toAdd);
                System.out.println("coming monday is on: " + cal.getTime());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can use [TemporalAdjusters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html):

```
public String getNextMonday(String date, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    LocalDate monday = startDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    return formatter.format(monday);
}
```

Call with

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
String nextMonday = getNextMonday("23/02/2015", formatter);
```